# Do I have to close a file if I use Get-ChildItem

Tags: powershell

Im using Get-ChildItem to read files in a folder then I get the lastwritetime for each file and sort them.

Do I have to close the files after getting the lastwritetime?

Comment: `Get-ChildItem` doesn't "open" the file, it asks an underlying API for metadata _about_ the file - there's nothing to be closed

Comment: No. This is just a list of info for the files. No streams or locks are taking place.

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen - Write that as an answer, rather than just a comment - it's the correct response to the question, unquestionably.

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen Thanks, that makes sense.

Comment: @ArcSet So if I were to check if a file exists by using System.IO.File]::Exists, would that create memory that I should release?

Comment: Well it depends if its in a loop no need. Once the loop is ended it will be marked for cleanup by garbage collection. The .net framework uses Garbage collection to clean all the memory for you. If you have created the variable outside a loop or a function then you can empty its contents by just doing $Example = $null. This will allow garbage collection to clean it all up

Comment: @moehajer No - the memory temporarily allocated by managed code will be freed eventually by the garbage collector - if you have a problem or question about how to avoid excessive memory allocation specifically in PowerShell I'd suggest you ask that, otherwise I'd say you don't need to be concerned with it

Answer (score 1):

No. This is just a list of info for the files. No streams or locks are taking place

Answer (score 0):

As has already been mentioned, the answer is **no**.

The reason being that when you use `Get-ChildItem` against the file system it doesn't actually open any files - it interrogates an underlying API which then returns metadata *about* the files in the file system - so there's no file handle to be "closed".

---

From the comments on your question, I sense some confusion as to "why don't I need to manage system resource allocation in PowerShell?"

PowerShell runs on .NET, and the .NET runtime is garbage-collected. At some (undefined) point in time after a block of memory is no longer referenced by any pointers, the garbage collector will take care of freeing it, and you don't need to worry about managing this process yourself.

Of course there are situations in which resource allocation is external to the runtime, and has to be managed, but the usual pattern in .NET is to implement the `IDisposable` interface when defining classes that depend on unmanaged resources. An example is a `StreamReader` (with which you could read a text file). In `C#` you can use the `using` directive to automatically dispose of such an object once execution leaves the scope in which it's required:

```
using(StreamReader reader = File.OpenText("C:\path\to\file.txt"))
{
    // use reader in here
}
// at this point, reader.Dispose() has been called automatically
```

In PowerShell, there is no such semantic construct. What I usually do when allocating many disposable objects is wrap them in a `try`/`finally` block:

```
try {
    $FileReader = [System.IO.File]::OpenText("C:\path\to\file.txt")
    # user $FileReader here
}
finally {
    if($FileReader -ne $null){
        $FileReader.Dispose()
    }
}
```

Of course all of this is hidden away from you when invoking `Get-Content` for example - the developer of the underlying function in the file system provider has already taken care of disposing the object by the time the pipeline stops running. It's really only needed when you want to write your own cmdlets and interact with more "primitive" types directly

I hope this sheds some light on your confusion